# Programming language with multiple object models

Tags: r, oop, programming-languages

I know that the programming language `R` has multiple object models (i.e. S3, S4, Reference class, S6). I wondered if there are other programming languages that also use multiple object models?

What justifies this complexity? Is it related to backwards compatibility or are there other advantages?

Comment: You can happily use R without ever having to deal with reference classes. So, where is the issue of complexity? Anyway, this seems off-topic.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I understand that S3 is used very often and the other two models have a rather shadowy existence. I'm mainly interested in why the other models exist? For me it feels a bit like R has these features only to belong to the OO language?If it is off-topic, can you recommend another StackExchange forum?

Comment: S3 has sone serious limitations. Often these don't matter but sometimes you need to be able, e.g., to dispatch methods depending on the classes of more than one parameter.

Comment: Why do you assume that a Stack Exchange site for your question exists?

Comment: My question is of theoretical nature. I wonder why all other OO programming languages I know (i.e. Python, Java, C++) get along with one object model and R has four of them. There has to me a StackExchange Forum for every immaginable question ;)

Comment: These different systems in R represent different approaches to object-orientation. S3 is hard-wired into R and is used in every interactive session. S4 is an attempt to formalize and encapsulate classes, as well as allowing multiple dispatch. Reference classes are an attempt at a more full-blown encapsulated OO system with pass-by-reference semantics. Other OO systems like S6 and ggproto are add-ons via packages. The reasons are mostly historical, but to me it seems a strength of R that it is possible to create multiplte different but consistent OO systems.

Answer (score 0):

Python 2 has two object models (new-style and classic classes). However, this is manly used for backwards compatibility (see [here](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#new-style-and-classic-classes)).